# Material UI Tabs with routes

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So I'm using Material UI Tabs, and I'm trying when a user taps on tab it redirects him to a tab with a link but it would be still in the same main page

**Example of what i'm looking for please notice the link changes as the tabs changes:**

[image]

**`Material UI VerticalTabs`**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Tabs from '@mui/material/Tabs';
import Tab from '@mui/material/Tab';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

function TabPanel(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`vertical-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`vertical-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box sx={{ p: 3 }}>
          <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

TabPanel.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  index: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};

function a11yProps(index) {
  return {
    id: `vertical-tab-${index}`,
    'aria-controls': `vertical-tabpanel-${index}`,
  };
}

export default function VerticalTabs() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{ flexGrow: 1, bgcolor: 'background.paper', display: 'flex', height: 224 }}
    >
      <Tabs
        orientation="vertical"
        variant="scrollable"
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        aria-label="Vertical tabs example"
        sx={{ borderRight: 1, borderColor: 'divider' }}
      >
        <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
        <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
        <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
      </Tabs>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        Item One
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        Item Two
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
        Item Three
      </TabPanel>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

I know that I have to use `react-router-dom` but I didn't know how to implement, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you're looking for nested routes. this article can be a good start https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-router-nested-routes/

Answer (score 2):

Create a route component or destructive the routes in App.js. Just install react-router-dom and use BrowserRouter as Route as the Parent tag. Then add routes and structure your routes for your pages there.

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-route-dom'
```

```js
<Router>
   <Routes>
     <Route path='/pageName' element={<pageName/>}>
     <Route path='/pageName2' element={<pageName2/>}>
   </Routes>
</Router>
```

Also refer react router v6 [docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/browser-router). This [playlist](https://youtu.be/UWYOC8g5N_0) would helpful to using different routing mechanism. In your case you need to watch the tutorial 8 to do the nested routes. If you're a person who familiar with v5 and want to know the changes in v6, then refer this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k2Zk5cbiZhg&t=406s) also.